# Nested query returns empty set - MySQL

Tags: mysql

Nested query - NOT IN (select ub.book_id from User u, User_Book ub where u.id = 5 and u.id = ub.user_id) issue

I have tried running the query without the nested query, which is does work but when I add the nested query, is get the empty set.

Overall Code:

```
    public Collection<Bookmark> getBooks(boolean isBookmarked, long userId) {
        Collection<Bookmark> result = new ArrayList<>();

                try {
                    Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                //Dao connection
                try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?useSSL=false", "root",
                        "password"); /* a) Database User Profile: root is who the user is b) Database user password */
                        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();) /* execute mysql queries */ {

                    String query = "";
                    if (!isBookmarked) {
                        query = "Select b.id, title, image_url, publication_year, GROUP_CONCAT(a.name SEPARATOR ',') AS authors, book_genre_id, " +
                                            "amazon_rating from Book b, Author a, Book_Author ba where b.id = ba.book_id and ba.author_id = a.id and " + 
                                            "b.id NOT IN (select ub.book_id from User u, User_Book ub where u.id = " + userId +
                                            " and u.id = ub.user_id) group by b.id";                
                    } /*else {
                        query = "Select b.id, title, image_url, publication_year, GROUP_CONCAT(a.name SEPARATOR ',') AS authors, book_genre_id, " +
                                "amazon_rating from Book b, Author a, Book_Author ba where b.id = ba.book_id and ba.author_id = a.id and " + 
                                "b.id IN (select ub.book_id from User u, User_Book ub where u.id = " + userId +
                                " and u.id = ub.user_id) group by b.id";
                    }*/

                    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);                

                    while (rs.next()) {

                        long id = rs.getLong("id");
                        String title = rs.getString("title");
                        String imageUrl = rs.getString("image_url");
                        int publicationYear = rs.getInt("publication_year");
//                      String publisher = rs.getString("name");
                        String[] authors = rs.getString("authors").split(",");
                        int genre_id = rs.getInt("book_genre_id");
                        BookGenreEnum genre = BookGenreEnum.values()[genre_id];
                        double amazonRating = rs.getDouble("amazon_rating");


                        System.out.println("id: " + id + ", title: " + title + ", publication year: " + publicationYear + ", authors: " + String.join(", ", authors) + ", genre: " + genre + ", amazonRating: " + amazonRating);

                        Bookmark bookmark = BookmarkManager.getInstance().createBook(id, title, imageUrl, publicationYear, null, authors, genre, amazonRating/*, values[7]*/);
                        result.add(bookmark); 
                    }
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                return result;
            }
```

WITH NESTED QUERY:

```
Select b.id, title, image_url, publication_year, GROUP_CONCAT(a.name SEPARATOR ',') AS authors, book_genre_id, amazon_rating 
from Book b, Author a, Book_Author ba 
where b.id = ba.book_id and ba.author_id = a.id and b.id 
NOT IN (select ub.book_id from User u, User_Book ub where u.id = 5 and u.id = ub.user_id) group by b.id;
```

WITH NESTED QUERY - MySQL result:

```
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

WITHOUT NESTED QUERY:

```
Select b.id, title, image_url, publication_year, p.name, GROUP_CONCAT(a.name SEPARATOR ',') AS authors, book_genre_id, amazon_rating, created_date 
from Book b, Publisher p, Author a, Book_Author ba 
where b.publisher_id = p.id and b.id = ba.book_id and ba.author_id = a.id 
group by b.id;
```

WITHOUT NESTED QUERY - MySQL result

```
mysql> select * from book \G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
                    id: 1
                 title: The Complete Software Developer's Career Guide
             image_url: https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51yr12gkjRL._SY346_.jpg
      publication_year: 2017
          publisher_id: 1
         book_genre_id: 10
         amazon_rating: 4.7
   kid_friendly_status: 0
kid_friendly_marked_by: 4
             shared_by: 5
          created_date: 2019-06-22 09:17:29
*************************** 2. row ***************************
                    id: 2
                 title: The Rational Male
             image_url: https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51dS%2Bd%2BwZEL._SX322_BO1,204,203,200_.jpg
      publication_year: 2013
          publisher_id: 2
         book_genre_id: 8
         amazon_rating: 4.5
   kid_friendly_status: 1
kid_friendly_marked_by: 3
             shared_by: 5
          created_date: 2019-06-22 09:17:29
*************************** 3. row ***************************
                    id: 3
                 title: The 48 Laws of Power
             image_url: https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41EhEN9nsmL._SY346_.jpg
      publication_year: 2000
          publisher_id: 3
         book_genre_id: 5
         amazon_rating: 4.5
   kid_friendly_status: 1
kid_friendly_marked_by: 5
             shared_by: 5
          created_date: 2019-06-22 09:17:29
*************************** 4. row ***************************
                    id: 4
                 title: Rich Dad Poor Dad
             image_url: https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51N2wpwLcVL._SX342_.jpg
      publication_year: 2017
          publisher_id: 4
         book_genre_id: 8
         amazon_rating: 4.6
   kid_friendly_status: 0
kid_friendly_marked_by: 3
             shared_by: 4
          created_date: 2019-06-22 09:17:30
*************************** 5. row ***************************
                    id: 5
                 title: Eat That Frog!
             image_url: https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51N38zCWljL._SX342_.jpg
      publication_year: 2017
          publisher_id: 5
         book_genre_id: 8
         amazon_rating: 4.6
   kid_friendly_status: 0
kid_friendly_marked_by: 4
             shared_by: 5
          created_date: 2019-06-22 09:17:30
```

This meant to show all the books a particular user has bookmarked.

Comment: Your query has several problems, the biggest being that you are grouping by only one column but then selecting non aggregate columns.  Also, you are using old school join syntax.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply, but I still don't get what your saying...I am a newbie college student.

Comment: Please add sample input _and_ output data, for all tables.  Show us what the problem is.

Comment: Tim, could you give me an example of this?

Comment: Not related to JAVA at all. Why do you think that query with nested query should return records? Maybe you have such data that empty cursor with nested query is a correct result?

Comment: The nested query is to get only the books the user has saved